# Android NDK system mismatch - Android and Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, arm, x86-64

I get this error in the CMakeOutput.log:

The target system is: Android - 1 - armv7-a
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.17134 - AMD64

when I try to build my project with NDK.

this is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.my.tester"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++14"
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
             jniLibs.srcDirs 'MySDK'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'MySDK', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Do you run CMake from Android Studio?

Comment: I run "gradle build" from the command line.

Comment: Gradle should have generated cake_build_command.txt file. Please post it.

Comment: I have only these files: cmake_server_log.txt, package-aware-r.txt, manifest-merger-debug-report.txt, cmake_server_log.txt, CMakeCache.txt, CMakeLists.txt, R.txt.

Comment: Could you please share your **gradle.build**?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Is this the problem? ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
   }

Comment: No, **abiFilters** is OK

Comment: Maybe I should run everything with CygWin?

Comment: No, don't need CygWin

Comment: Have you installed CMake from Android Studio SDK Manager? Which version of NDK do you have in **ndk-bundle** folder?

Comment: Yes, it's installed. This is the source.properties file in ndk-bundle: Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 19.2.5345600

Comment: Not sure what I did but it seems to work now.. Thanks!

Comment: That's the best!